# Javascript: read Stylesheets fontsize from body-tag

Tags: javascript, html, tags, font-size

on a website there is this css-style:

```
<style>
body{font-size: 110%;}
</style>
```

now i want to read with javascript the fontsize of the body-tag.

What must I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the style using [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

> The Window.getComputedStyle() method returns an object containing the
>   values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active
>   stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may
>   contain. Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs
>   provided by the object, or by indexing with CSS property names.

Working snippet:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('body')
const style = getComputedStyle(element)

console.log(style.fontSize);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
      font-size: 110%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by using Web API, window method called getComputedStyle:

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const bodyFontSize = getComputedStyle(body).fontSize;
console.log(bodyFontSize);
```

Comment: 0


thank you for both answers.

but there is a problem: I set percent (110%) and the result is 22px

I want a solution where the result is percent, when i set percent.